# requirejs and ByteBuffer

Tags: javascript, requirejs

im an javascript newbie and google didnt helps:

I tryed to load ByteBuffer.js in an require.js module:

```
define(['js/ByteBufferAB'], function (ByteBufferAB) {

var MessageBase = function () {
    this._version = 0; // unsinged int 16 bits
    this._dataType = "";

};

MessageBase.prototype.toBytes = function () {
    //console.log( new ByteBufferAB(58));
    var headerBytes = new ByteBufferAB(58); // <-- here comes the error
    headerBytes.clear();
    return headerBytes;
};


return MessageBase;

});
```

with the same syntax math.js is properly loaded.

But with ByteBufferAB.js the following error comes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you included ByteBufferAB.js in your project directory? Try opening F12 Developer Tools, open the Network tab, and see where it's trying to load it from.

Comment: yes, ByteBufferAB.js ist in my project directory. console.log (require.defined("js/ByteBufferAB")); returns True

Comment: What ByteBuffer distribution are you using? If `require.defined("js/ByteBufferAB")); returns True` It's possible, that your module just returned unefined.

Comment: Im using the following Distro: *ByteBufferAB.js uses an ArrayBuffer as its backing buffer, accessed through a DataView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `define` call you refer to the module as `js/ByteBufferAB` so RequireJS looks for a module named `js/ByteBufferAB`. However, the module [defines itself](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js/blob/dfdefb8201870396b082c5f8bf6a4919d7c092d8/dist/ByteBufferAB.js) as `ByteBuffer`:

```
/* AMD */ else if (typeof define === 'function' && define["amd"])
    define("ByteBuffer", ["Long"], function(Long) { return  loadByteBuffer(Long); });
```

Because the module name is hardcoded, you need to have a mapping like this in your `paths` in the configuration you give to RequireJS:

```
ByteBuffer: "js/ByteBufferAB"
```

and you need to refer to the module as `ByteBuffer` in your `define` call.

None of this would be required if the developers for this library had not hardcoded a name but they have, and so here we are.

Comment: Thanks, additionally i make an mistake in the path-configuration...but your answer help me!